# Problema para mostrar alerta

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Estoy intentando realizar una inserción en un formulario usando un servidor local pero el problema no es la inserción en si, sino que tengo una validación para que en caso de que el producto y la sucursal coincidan no me deje insertar y que el anuncio que aparezca sea "Ya existe" pero no se muestra ya comprobé que no se inserta, la inserción y su alerta si se muestran. para el formulario uso conbobox que me dan la id de la sucursal y el producto que de esa manera no tengo que enviarlas a través de páginas, sino que se hace una consulta de estas ya que son foranes de inventario

Cliente:

```
        const NuevoInventario = () => {
        const [alerta, setAlerta] = useState(null);
        const initialState = {
            //campos de la inserción                                                                                     
        };                                                                                          
                                                                                   
          useEffect(() => {
            // Obtener la lista de sucursales
            axios
            .get("http://localhost:5000/sucursales")
            .then((response) => {
                setSucursales(response.data);
                // Después de obtener la lista de sucursales, obtener la lista de productos
                return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/existencias");
            })
            .then((response) => {
                setExistencias(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(
                "Error al obtener la lista de sucursales o productos:",
                error.message
                );
            });
        }, []);

        const handleChange = (e) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setInventario({
            ...inventario,
            [name]: name === "estatus" ? parseInt(value) : value,
            });
        };

        const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            try {
            // Check for duplicate inventory before attempting to insert
            const checkDuplicateResponse = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:5000/isertarInventario",
                inventario
            );

            if (checkDuplicateResponse.data.error) {
                // Si hay un duplicado, muestra una alerta y no procedas con la inserción
                setAlerta(checkDuplicateResponse.data.error);
                return;
            }

            // If no duplicate, proceed with the insertion
            await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/insertarInventario", inventario);
            console.log("Inventario insertado correctamente.");

            // Show the alert for successful insertion
            setAlerta("¡Inventario insertado correctamente!");

            // Reset the form
            setInventario(initialState);
            } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error al insertar inventario:", error.message);
            }
        };
```

Servidor:

```
app.post('/insertarInventario', async (req, res) => {
const { cantidad, id_sucursal, id_producto } = req.body;

// Check if the combination of id_producto and id_sucursal already exists
const checkDuplicateSql = 'SELECT id_i FROM inventario WHERE id_p = ? AND id_s = ?';
const checkDuplicateValues = [id_producto, id_sucursal];

try {
  const duplicateResults = await db.promise().query(checkDuplicateSql, checkDuplicateValues);
    if (duplicateResults[0].length > 0) {
      // si es duplicado
      res.status(400).json({ error: 'Ya existe' });
    }
```

Comment: Corrigo mi comentario anterior, hay un typo en la URL `checkDuplicateResponse`, tienes `isertarInventario` me parece que debería ser `insertarInventario `